# DataBinding Dictionary Collection to RichTexbox showing both keys and values of a collection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

MarkUp for XAML:

```
<RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="120" Margin="359,554,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="306" Name="duplicateCompXMLVarRichTextBox">            
    <FlowDocument>               
        <Paragraph>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"/>
            <!-- <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Key}"/> -->
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

CodeBehind:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> componentXMLDuplicates = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
componentXMLDuplicates= Helper.PopulateCollectionWithData();
duplicateCompXMLVarRichTextBox.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
duplicateCompXMLVarRichTextBox.DataContext = componentXMLDuplicates;
```

The problem here is i can only show either Keys or Values of a dictionary collection in the WPF Window. Is there any possibility of displaying both at the same time using proper formatting or spaces between them? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can achieve this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                         <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
                               <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                      <DataTemplate>
                                           <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                       </DataTemplate>
                                 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                          </ItemsControl>
                   </StackPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Superman! @nit Thanks a lot :).  I will mark this as approved once stackoverflow permits me.